# Mockito throws UnfinishedStubbingException for no apparent reason

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write a "simple" unit test. Mockito however always tells me there is an `UnfinishedStubbingException`.

The code line Mockito is exposing as culprit is the following:

```
when(myServiceIdFactory.get(any())).thenReturn((SortedSet<MyServiceId>) Set.of(emptyId));
```

Here is the whole unit test code

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceIdProcessorTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyServiceIdProcessor myServiceIdProcessor;
  @MockBean
  private MyServiceIdFactory myServiceIdFactory;

  @Test
  public void shouldFilterProductsWithNoId() {
    Product productWithNoId = new Product();
    MyServiceId emptyId = new MyServiceId();
    when(myServiceIdFactory.get(any())).thenReturn((SortedSet<MyServiceId>) Set.of(emptyId));

    CatalogDTO catalogDTO = new CatalogDTO();
    Envelope<CatalogDTO, Product> envelopeToTest = Envelope.products(List.of(productWithNoId));

    Envelope returnedEnvelope = myServiceIdProcessor.enrichCatalog(envelopeToTest);

    assertThat(returnedEnvelope.getProducts()).hasSize(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the MyServiceIdFactory interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the following cast exception:

```
 when(myServiceIdFactory.get(any())).thenReturn((SortedSet<MyServiceId>) Set.of(emptyId));
```

`Set.of(foo)` can't be casted to a `SortedSet`. The exception however seemed to be swallowed and overwritten by Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Try to `spy()` the `MyServiceIdFactory` before define the bahavoir

```
  @Test
  public void shouldFilterProductsWithNoId() {
    // Arrange
    Product productWithNoId = new Product();
    MyServiceId emptyId = new MyServiceId();
    MyServiceIdFactory spyMyServiceIdFactory = spy(myServiceIdFactory);
    SortedSet<MyServiceId> set = (SortedSet<MyServiceId>) Set.of(emptyId);
    doReturn(set).when(spyMyServiceIdFactory).get(any());

    CatalogDTO catalogDTO = new CatalogDTO();
    Envelope<CatalogDTO, Product> envelopeToTest = Envelope.products(List.of(productWithNoId));

    // Act
    Envelope returnedEnvelope = spyMyServiceIdFactory.enrichCatalog(envelopeToTest);

    // Assert
    assertThat(returnedEnvelope.getProducts()).hasSize(0);
  }
```